# LINQ Include and Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a WEB API project, which uses Database First model.
I have base class `Building` entity, and `MultiApartmentBuilding` entity which is inherited from Building. Also I have an `Apartment` entity which is connected with `Building` entities in one to many relationship. I want to get a particular apartment by given apartment id, and include some `MultiApartmentBuilding` info.

So far, I have tried to achieve desirable result through `Include()` LINQ method, but I have encountered a problem that I cannot include `MultiapartmentBuilding`.

This is my `Building` class.

```
public abstract class Building
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BuildingState State { get; set; }
    public BuildingType Type { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public MultilingualString Description { get; set; }
    public string MainImg { get; set; }
    public bool IsBuilt { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `MultiApartmentBuilding` class.

```
public class MultiApartmentBuilding : Building
{
    public int GroundFloorCount { get; set; }
    public double FloorHeight { get; set; }
    public int? WallId { get; set; }
    public Wall Wall { get; set; }       
}
```

This is my `Apartment` class.

```
public class Apartment : EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public Building Building { get; set; }
    public Common.Enums.ApartmentState State { get; set; }
    public AccessibilityState Accessibility { get; set; }
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public bool IsPentHouse { get; set; }
}
```

This is my LINQ Query which should return apartment.

```
var apartment = _context.Apartments
    .Where(id => id.Id == apartmentId)
    .Include(building => building.Building)
        .ThenInclude(address => address.Address)
        .ThenInclude(city => city.City)
        .ThenInclude(cityName => cityName.Name)
   .Include(district => district.Building.Address.District)
        .ThenInclude(districtName => districtName.Name)
   .Include(street => street.Building.Address.Street)
   .Include(condPrices => condPrices.ConditionPrices)
        .ThenInclude(condition => condition.Condition)
        .ThenInclude(conditionName => conditionName.Name)
        .ThenInclude(conditionNameTranslation => conditionNameTranslation.Translations)
   .Include(builder => builder.Building.Builder)
        .ThenInclude(brandName => brandName.BrandName)
        .ThenInclude(brandNameTrans => brandNameTrans.Translations)
    .Include(builderBussinesAddress => builderBussinesAddress.Building.Builder.BusinessAddress)
         .ThenInclude(tranlsations => tranlsations.Translations)
   .Include(descriptipon => descriptipon.Description)
        .ThenInclude(descriptionName => descriptionName.Translations)
```

The problem of this query is that I cannot get access to `MultiApartmentBuilding` fields. I can only have access to `Building` fields, although `MultiApartmentBuilding` is inherited from `Building`. Is there any way to have access also to `MultiApartmenBuilding` fields?

Comment: You can format code blocks by indenting it by 4 spaces and keeping one empty line between text and code. No need for back-ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Including `Building` will also include `MultiApartmentBuilding` entries (in fact all types deriving from `Building`).

You can use C# 7.0's pattern matching to test and cast at the same time (where `apartments` is the result of the query):

```
foreach (Apartment apartment in apartments) {
    // Access common Building field.
    Console.WriteLine(apartment.Building.Id);

    // Access specialized field from derived building type.
    if (apartment.Building is MultiApartmentBuilding maBuilding) {
        Console.WriteLine(maBuilding.GroundFloorCount);
    }
}
```

If you have many types of buildings, you can use pattern matching in the switch statement

```
switch (apartment.Building)
{
    case MultiApartmentBuilding maBuilding:
        Console.WriteLine(maBuilding.GroundFloorCount);
        break;
    case Igloo igloo:
        Console.WriteLine(igloo.SnowQuality);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("all other building types");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the child's class attributes. In other words, if you have a Building, you can't access its **MultiApartmentBuilding** attributes, because you don't even know if it really is a **MultiApartmentBuilding**. 
What I would do in this case would be to change your **Apartment** class and use the type **MultiApartmentBuilding** instead of **Building**:

```
public class Apartment : EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public MultiApartmentBuilding MultiApartmentBuilding { get; set; }
    public Common.Enums.ApartmentState State { get; set; }
    public AccessibilityState Accessibility { get; set; }
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public bool IsPentHouse { get; set; }
 }
```